# What's the best way to split my thesis into multiple tex files?

Tags: sectioning, thesis

I am using a LaTeX template for my thesis and it has separate tex files for each chapter which are added to a main.tex file using `\input`. I would like to know if it's a good idea to do the same for each section of a chapter. Is it recommended? How about one file for every subsection? What are the advantages or drawbacks?

Comment: TeX doesn't care so it's a question about you and your editor. so easier for you to answer than anyone else. For example if you want to change `color` to `colour` throughout the thesis and you have split your source into 50 files, that is either a pain or no problem at all depending how easily your editor does multi-file edits.

Comment: MastersDoctoralThesis? If yes, make sure to get the latest version of the template. Or use none at all. If yes, do i get a cookie for having psychic powers?

Comment: @Johannes_B Doctoral.

Comment: can you give me a Link?

Comment: @Johannes_B Ah now i understood your comment :-) Yeah that's the one. Masters/Doctoral Thesis LaTeX Template Version 1.42

Comment: @Johannes_B http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis

Comment: Ok, i thought so. Get the new version now: http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis But be advised, not using a template is safer.

Comment: @Johannes_B Could you please say why it is safer? in what sense?

Comment: If you are interested in why i am so direct here, you might be interested about [the history of the template](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/templateConfusion/blob/master/ourFamousThesisTemplate.md).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do we have a similar question or do you want to convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: if you already have chapters in separate files, it's quite reasonable to subdivide your sections into more separate files, pulled in with `\input`.  you might consider using `\include` for the chapters in your main file (so that they can be worked on separately, using `\includeonly`).  but a warning ... `\include` always starts a new (right-hand) page, it can't be nested in an `\include`d file, and if you put the `\chapter` info in the main file before its `\include` statement, it will be deferred until after that file is processed (so always keep `\chapter` *within* the `\include`d file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all use `\include` instead of `\input` for your chapter files; included files always start a new page so that's OK for chapters. You can use the `\includeonly` macro in the preamble to specify which particular files are to be included for processing. For instance:

```
\documentclass{...}
\includeonly{chap1,chap3} % process only chap1.tex & chap3.tex
...
\begin{document} 
\include{chap1} % processed this time
\include{chap2} % not processed this time
\include{chap3} % processed this time
```

Excluded files will be treated as unchanged so that numbering, etc., will be consistent across the whole document.

After that it is up to you whether you like a smaller number of larger files or a larger number of smaller files; see David Carlisle's comment about this.
However you can only `\input` subsidiary files into an included file.